# I want to change html content with my own

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I am using lxml and beautifulsoup library, actually my goal is to translate text of the specific tags out of the whole html code, I am successful at translating it using translators library, but what I want is, I want to replace the text of specific tags with the translated text.

Here is the html code:

```
<p class="text_obisnuit2">What is a performer?</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership: Performer</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Question:</p>
```

So the above html has text in english. what type of output I want is should be romanian:

```
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Ce este un interpret? </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Conducere: interpret </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Întrebare: </p>
```

I think you people have understood this.

So I want to set a loop for the specific xpath in which all the translated text should be inserted one after another.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import translators as ts
import json
import numpy as np
import regex
import selenium
from lxml import html
import time
import lxml.html

#r=requests.get(input('Enter the URL of your HTML page:\n'))
r=requests.get('https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/definition-what-is-a-performer.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
page=r.content
element = html.fromstring(page)

    
for item in element.xpath('//div[@align = "justify"]/p[@class = "text_obisnuit2"]'):  
    text=item.text.content()    
    output=ts.google(text, from_language='en', to_language='ro') 

    for z in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'text_obisnuit2'}):
        var1=z.string

        var1.replace_with(var1.replace(var1, output))
        print(soup)
```

The output I am getting:

```
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Ce este un interpret? </p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Ce este un interpret? </p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Ce este un interpret? </p>

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'
```

The output I want:

```
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Ce este un interpret? </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Conducere: interpret </p>
<p class = "text_obisnuit2"> Întrebare: </p>
```

**NOTE:**

There should be a loop to insert the translated text in all these tags, I mean all tags should get its own text after translation using a loop.

I can not explain more, any one guide me please.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the tag with the translated text, use [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) as follows:

```
import translators as ts
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p class="text_obisnuit2">What is a performer?</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Leadership: Performer</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Question:</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="text_obisnuit2"):
    translated_text = ts.google(tag.text, from_language="en", to_language="ro")
    tag.replace_with(translated_text)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
Ce este un interpret?
Leadership: interpret
Întrebare:
```

---

Note: The output for the text of "Leadership: Performer" is not being well translated by the `translators` library.

Comment: Just a comment to help the user asking: `var1.replace_with(var1.replace(var1, output))` is called recursively I think. The parametre of `replace_with` should be a string not yet another variable. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-the-tags-contents-and-replace-with-the-given-string-using-beautifulsoup/).

Comment: I edited your code as:     tag.string.replace_with(tag.string.replace(tag.string,translated_text)), so the whole html code is returned, not only the text. By the way thanks for helping.

Comment: By your method, the translator library can not be used to translate tag text more than 5000 words, so I used other way that I found, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way later, its great, by this method I can even translate articles having more than 5000 words.

```
articles=[]
for item in element.xpath('//div[@align = "justify"]/p[@class = "text_obisnuit"]'):  

    #texts=item.text_content()
    #texts=texts.split('"', 50)
    articles.append(item.text_content())

translated_articles=[]
for text in articles:
    output=ts.google(text, from_language='en', to_language='ro')
    translated_articles.append(output)
    for i,z in zip(translated_articles,soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'text_obisnuit'})):
        var=z.string
        var.replace_with(var.replace(var, i))


#print(soup)
```